# How to access requested user object from jwt token in django serializers?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, jwt, one-to-one

> After **user-registration**, user wants to post data into Client model ( *OnetoOne* relationship with User model ). So, I want to access the requested **user object** inside the *serializer-class* to create a new row in Client model associated with the requested user.

**models.py**

```
class Client(models.Model):
user= models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, blank=False)
sex = models.CharField(max_length = 6, blank=False, null=False)
location = models.CharField(max_length = 30, null = False, blank = False)
```

**views.py**

```
class ClientRegister(GenericAPIView):
def post(self, request):  
    user = request.user
    serializer = ClientSerializer(data= request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():       
        serializer.save()           
        return Response(status= status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    else:
        return Response(data= 'Invalid Form', status= status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class ClientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):  
class Meta:
    model = Client
    fields = ['sex', 'location']  

def create(self, validated_data):
    sex = validated_data.get('sex')
    location = validated_data.get('location')         

    user =  #------ Want requested user object here ------#
    
    if user.is_client:    
        client = Client(user=user, sex=sex, location=location)
        client.save()
        return client
```

> I have manually added user oject into the **data** in `serializer = CientSerializer(data=request.data)`.
> But, It didn't work. Please, tell me how to pass it from `views.py` or how to access it in `serializers.py`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass user when you do serializer.save in post method of views like

```
def post(self, request):  
    u = request.user
    serializer = ClientSerializer(data= request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():       
        serializer.save(user=u)           
        return Response(status= status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    else:
        return Response(data= 'Invalid Form', status= status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Or you can read about passing context from views to serializers and in this context you can pass your required data like -

```
serializer = ClientSerializer(context = {'request':request}, data=request.data)
```

then you can have your request object in your serializers and you can get request.user or directly pass it in the context.

Comment: serializer = ClientSerializer(context={'user':request.user}, data=data). In serializer.py : user=self.context.get('user').

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass the user with sex and location in views

```
class ClientRegister(GenericAPIView):
    def post(self, request):  
        data = request.data
        user = request.user
         #add user in key
        data['user']=user
        serializer = ClientSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():       
            serializer.save()           
            return Response(status= status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(data= 'Invalid Form', status= status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

serializer:

```
class ClientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):  
   class Meta:
      model = Client
      fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: aren't request immutable ?

Comment: Thanks man for your approach. But, it didn't work.

Comment: in fields = '__all__' , user attribute also comes. But we don't want our client to enter 'user' themselves.

Answer (score 0):

> views.py

```
class ClientRegister(GenericAPIView):
  def post(self, request):  
    user = request.user
    serializer = ClientSerializer(context={'user':user}, data= request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():       
      serializer.save()           
      return Response(status= status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    else:
      return Response(data= 'Invalid Form', status= status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

> serializers.py

```
 class ClientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):  
   class Meta:
     model = Client
     fields = ['sex', 'location']  

   def create(self, validated_data):
     sex = validated_data.get('sex')
     location = validated_data.get('location')         

     user = self.context.get('user')

     if user.is_client:    
       client = Client(user=user, sex=sex, location=location)
       client.save()
       return client
```